# Setting initial directory for NSOpenPanel

Tags: swift, macos, nsopenpanel

I'm trying to get the user to select a file from a folder containing log files. So I want to display an NSOpenDialog showing the contents of that folder. I'm using Swift, so 10.9+

I see a number of threads on this topic here, but in spite of trying what appears to be the same code converted to Swift, it invariably returns to the Documents folder. Here's a sample:

```
    let fd: NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    fd.directoryURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("~/LauncherLogs", isDirectory: true)
    fd.canChooseDirectories = false
    fd.canChooseFiles = true
    fd.allowedFileTypes = ["log"]
    fd.runModal()
```

The folder in question does exist, and copy and pasting the path into the Go to Folder... in the Finder goes right there. Any ideas?

Comment: I strongly assume that you have to expand the tilde to the actual path ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to expand the `tilde` and NSString has a hand method for this so:

```
let launcherLogPathWithTilde = "~/LauncherLogs" as NSString
let expandedLauncherLogPath = launcherLogPathWithTilde.stringByExpandingTildeInPath
fd.directoryURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(expandedLauncherLogPath, isDirectory: true)
```

+1 upvote for Martin for mentioning it.

Comment: And this is what you get for assuming `NSURL.fileURLWithPath` would do expansions... *sigh*

Comment: I remember banging my head against the wall with this too! As user friendly apple devices and systems are, they certainly aren't developer friendly and if at best, extremely abstract.

Answer (score 4):

2022 version of [approved answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36437231/814730):

- `.stringByExpandingTildeInPath` → `.expandingTildeInPath`
- `.file` → `.fileURL`

```swift
let dialog = NSOpenPanel();
let launcherLogPathWithTilde = "~/LauncherLogs" as NSString
let expandedLauncherLogPath = launcherLogPathWithTilde.expandingTildeInPath
dialog.directoryURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: expandedLauncherLogPath, isDirectory: true)
```